# Can't open the VSVim project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vsvim

I have a clean install of Visual Studio 2010 with C# and F# installed and I am getting the following error when I try to open the solution cloned from github.

> D:\projects\VsVim\VsVim\VsVim.csproj :
>   error  : The project file
>   'D:\projects\VsVim\VsVim\VsVim.csproj'
>   cannot be opened.
>
> The project type is not supported by
>   this installation.

Is there a way to get more information about what exactly I am missing so that I can install the components?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to install the [Visual Studio 2010 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=47305cf4-2bea-43c0-91cd-1b853602dcc5&displaylang=en).

Comment: Just be sure to download the right one. [This might help if you have VS 2010 SP1](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/12b2e7e5-90a0-4045-8989-9bbf3622e495/)

Answer (score 2):

Noah is correct that the most likely problem is you need to install the Visual Studio SDK.  The full steps to getting VsVim to open and compile are the following (taken from the README.txt file in the enlistment).

1. Install the Visual Studio SDK
2. Run the script Populate-References.ps1 from the enlistment root directory
3. Open the Solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I feel pretty stupid not registering that I needed to install the SDK even though i read it.

Comment: @user568327 i wouldn't feel bad. I own this project and I've hit the exact same issue several times  :)